# "Displays" app crashes even before opening

Tags: 16.04, unity, display, launcher

I am trying to reposition my external monitor in the `Displays` app. But as soon as I select the app in `Search Your Computer`, a loading icon shows up for a few seconds and then nothing shows up. I suspect the app is crashing but I don't know why.

I looked into `dmesg` output and for every launch failure, I see one such log-

> [20630.390686] unity-control-c[17258]: segfault at 0 ip
>   00007f5401945924 sp 00007ffd6178a030 error 4 in
>   libc-2.23.so[7f540190a000+1c0000]

All other apps are opening just fine.

Does unity need any updating? If so, how should I do it?

EDIT: I tried launching the Display Settings from the command line but even that seg faulted like this-

```
$ gnome-control-center display 
i965_dri.so does not support the 0xffffffff PCI ID.

(gnome-control-center:19763): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: If you search for that error you get lots of interesting hits. Maybe see some of the comments in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1054435 and see if those are related. I'd concentrate on the environment passed to LibGL, which will be somewhat distribution agnostic.

Comment: I think any actual answer will be dependent on knowing what standard or third-party video drivers you are using.